# How can I use Twitter Bootstrap Dropdowns to include the first item as a toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

[Twitter Bootstrap Dropdowns Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns) show the following syntax for a dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

But instead I'd like the first item (`Drowdown trigger` above) to be included in the menu items.

Can you suggest a strategy to trigger a dropdown menu from a list including all items?

Here's an example HTML format of what I'm after.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li role="presentation"><a class="dropdown-toggle btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">General Support <b class="caret"></b></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sales</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Accounting</a></li>
</ul>
```

My actual use case is a little more complex and is the reason I can't simply use an HTML select input.

Comment: can't you just duplicate the toggle link inside the dropdown `<ul>` list?

Comment: I suppose Twitter Bootstrap doesn't give you that possibility from within the framework, you should probably build a custom drop-down to work as you desire or try the solution stated above by koala_dev

Comment: Fair enough. I think I can work with that for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just duplicate the trigger label as a `li`, it will appear as "included"

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Sales</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sales</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Accounting</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This wasn't what I was asking, but this solution will work even if not ideal.